# After "promisifying" net-ping resolve fire after timeout and not immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Using node-net-ping, version: 1.2.3

Wanted to convert the package to Promise, but my "resolve" fired only after 2-second delay.
Here's the code:

```
const ping = (host: string) => {
  let session = netPing.createSession();
  return new Promise<string | object>((resolve, reject) => {
    session.pingHost(
      host,
      function (
        error: NodeJS.ErrnoException,
        host: string,
        sent: number,
        rcvd: number
      ) {
        if (error) reject(error.toString());
        else
          resolve({
            host: host,
            recivedTime: rcvd,
            sentTime: sent,
            delta: rcvd - sent,
          });
      }
    );
  });
};
```

And then in routes I just call to ping:

```
router.get('/ping/:host', async (req, res) => {
  let result = await ping(req.params.host);
  res.json(result);
});
```

But the response comes back after a 2-second delay. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the ping function resolving or rejecting? Because 2 seconds is the default timeout of net-ping. Maybe the network request is timeing out after 2 seconds, rejecting the promise then.

Comment: The promise is resolving.

Comment: There is no reason (that would be visible from your sample code) that would make the promise resolve 2 seconds late. If a vanilla `session.pingHost()` works the way you would expect, the promisified version ought to do the same.